# A gloomy rebus with many outs

Tags: rebus

Solve the following rebus:

```
  5.OUT
  4.OUT
  3.OUT
  2.OUT
  1.OUT
```

The solution to this rebus is a gloomy phrase.

Comment: Looks like Utah's version history.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

I think Aggie is close, but I suspect it's more specific - to be exact, I am thinking it is

> Outnumbered Five to One

Answer (score 15):

How about perhaps:

> *Out* Numbered

Answer (score 12):

Is it

> Down and out for the count

Comment: This is what I thought it was when I first saw it. Seeing the accepted answer makes sense too, but this is my personal favorite.

Answer (score 3):

Is it

> Out of time. I'm referencing a failed bomb defusal

Answer (score 3):

I think question_asker is close to the money, but I think the solution is just

> DOWN AND OUT

because

> OUT is going DOWN the page from 5 to 1. And being DOWN AND OUT is synonymous for feeling gloomy

Answer (score 2):

Is it

> coming OUT of the closet

Answer (score 2):

I think it is

> Out of order.

Because

> It's the the order from $5$ to $1$. And it is gloomy too.

Comment: It can easily be argued 5-1 _is_ in order. Reverse order. Same can't be argued for 12435 or any other variation..

Comment: @Insane My answer totally assumes that it **is** in order. I just took the word 'out' and the order of the numbers to make the answer. :)

Answer (score 1):

How about:

> Beaten all ends up

---

Because

> Beaten could be a synonym for out.
>  Both the ends $5$ and $1$ are out.
>  The remaining numbers get out while going up, from $1$ to $5$ when natural order is considered.
>  Moreover, it is a gloomy phrase, as it means defeating totally.

Answer (score 1):

It may be

> **ALL OUT**   as all number are out.